# Finding maximal regions in data

Tags: pandas, image-processing, object-detection, detection, maxima

Suppose I have the following data:

```
import pandas pd

data = [44.5, 27.0, 22.0, 23.0, 23.0, 24.0, 23.0, 21.0, 22.0, 20.0, 22.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 20.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 16.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.5, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 21.0, 18.0, 17.0, 18.0, 16.0, 17.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 17.0, 17.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 17.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 19.0, 18.0, 18.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 54.0, 37.0, 31.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 28.0, 26.0, 27.5, 25.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 25.0, 30.0, 29.0, 26.0, 28.0, 26.0, 27.0, 25.0, 26.0, 26.0, 25.0, 24.0, 23.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 36.0, 29.0, 27.0, 26.0, 26.0, 27.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 25.0, 24.0, 25.0, 27.0, 25.0, 24.0, 24.0, 23.0, 24.0, 24.0, 23.5, 22.0, 22.0, 23.0, 23.0, 23.0, 22.0, 24.0, 41.0, 28.0, 26.0, 25.0, 24.0, 25.0, 24.0, 22.0, 22.0, 23.0, 23.0, 22.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 23.0, 21.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 20.0, 25.0, 21.0, 21.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 20.0, 21.0, 19.5, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 18.0, 18.0, 17.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 26.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 18.0, 20.0, 17.0, 19.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 17.0, 17.0, 18.0, 17.0, 20.0, 18.0, 18.0, 17.0, 17.0, 18.0, 16.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0, 23.0, 18.0, 17.0, 17.0, 16.0, 16.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 12.0, 14.0, 13.0, 14.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 20.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 13.0, 12.0, 14.0, 12.0, 13.0, 12.0, 12.0, 13.0, 12.0, 12.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 33.0, 27.0, 24.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0, 16.0, 15.0, 15.0, 16.0, 14.0, 14.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0, 13.0, 14.0, 14.0, 13.0, 14.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 24.0, 15.0, 16.0, 14.0, 14.0, 16.0, 15.5, 15.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 16.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 14.0, 17.0, 26.0, 21.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 18.0, 19.0, 22.0, 47.0, 31.0, 30.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 27.0, 26.0, 28.0, 29.0, 31.0, 29.0, 30.0, 30.0, 32.0, 36.0, 27.0, 29.0, 29.0, 27.0, 30.0, 28.0, 27.0, 26.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 31.0, 38.0, 33.0, 31.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 29.0, 30.0, 33.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 31.0, 31.0, 33.0, 32.0, 31.0, 32.0, 32.0, 33.5, 32.0, 32.0, 34.0, 41.0, 99.0, 73.0, 76.0, 64.0, 64.0, 72.0, 72.0, 68.0, 63.0, 66.0, 70.0, 70.0, 62.0, 63.0, 63.0, 72.0, 66.0, 66.0, 65.0, 62.0, 65.0, 63.0, 59.0, 59.0, 62.0, 61.0, 62.0, 61.0, 60.0, 64.0, 82.0, 69.0, 67.0, 67.0, 62.0, 68.5, 65.0, 66.0, 64.0, 66.0, 66.0, 62.0, 65.0, 65.0, 61.0, 68.0, 64.0, 64.0, 65.0, 65.0, 69.0, 66.0, 62.0, 64.0, 64.0, 70.0, 65.0, 65.0, 67.0, 75.0, 167.0, 120.0, 111.0, 102.0, 100.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.5, 96.0, 97.0, 101.5, 99.0, 95.0, 87.0, 89.0, 101.0, 94.0, 94.0, 93.0, 95.0, 100.0, 96.0, 96.0, 94.0, 101.0, 119.0, 134.0, 140.0, 149.0, 211.0, 219.0, 160.0, 127.0, 115.0, 112.0, 108.0, 101.0, 96.0, 90.0, 91.0, 94.0, 90.0, 86.0, 85.0, 89.0, 94.0, 91.0, 83.0, 82.0, 81.0, 86.0, 82.0, 82.0, 77.0, 79.0, 83.0, 84.0, 77.0, 76.0, 83.0, 132.5, 108.0, 104.0, 97.0, 99.0, 97.0, 94.0, 90.0, 85.0, 87.0, 92.0, 86.0, 86.0, 84.0, 83.0, 92.0, 86.0, 86.0, 86.0, 83.0, 86.0, 83.0, 78.0, 77.0, 81.0, 81.0, 76.0, 78.0, 77.0, 78.0, 98.0, 91.0, 84.0, 83.0, 81.0, 84.0, 81.0, 81.0, 78.0, 76.0, 82.0, 79.0, 78.0, 74.0, 77.0, 81.0, 78.0, 78.0, 80.0, 79.0, 85.0, 76.0, 76.5, 75.0, 76.0, 79.0, 75.0, 73.0, 70.0, 73.0, 109.0, 93.0, 91.0, 85.0, 85.0, 88.0, 82.0, 81.0, 79.0, 76.0, 82.0, 78.0, 80.0, 75.0, 77.0, 81.0, 79.0, 76.0, 78.0, 74.0, 81.0, 78.0, 74.0, 72.0, 73.0, 77.0, 74.0, 75.0, 71.0, 73.0, 95.0, 83.0, 83.0, 81.0, 79.0, 83.0, 79.0, 76.0, 75.0, 74.0, 84.0, 74.0, 75.5, 75.0, 76.0, 86.0, 79.0, 76.0, 73.0, 74.0, 80.0, 77.0, 75.5, 70.0, 73.0, 76.0, 73.0, 73.0, 70.0, 80.0, 112.0, 88.0, 89.0, 86.0, 87.0, 89.0, 87.0, 85.0, 85.0, 82.0, 90.0, 88.0, 87.0, 87.0, 86.0, 92.0, 87.0, 88.0, 86.0, 88.0, 90.0, 93.0, 89.0, 85.0, 90.0, 94.0, 91.0, 84.5, 86.0, 86.0, 110.0, 104.0, 102.0, 94.5, 101.0, 106.0, 100.0, 96.0, 89.0, 92.0, 99.0, 95.0, 95.0, 94.0, 95.0, 108.0, 104.0, 98.0, 110.0, 106.0, 117.0, 112.0, 108.5, 107.0, 105.0, 109.0, 108.0, 110.0, 103.0, 112.0, 187.0, 152.0, 138.0, 137.0, 135.5, 146.0, 136.0, 129.0, 130.0, 134.0, 141.0, 133.0, 137.0, 131.0, 137.0, 153.0, 147.0, 140.0, 142.0, 150.0, 174.0, 157.0, 149.0, 145.0, 151.0, 160.0, 147.0, 136.0, 132.0, 138.0, 254.0, 229.0, 222.0, 212.0, 207.0, 230.0, 210.0, 206.0, 201.0, 194.0, 209.0, 199.0, 201.0, 202.0, 200.0, 225.0, 220.0, 201.0, 202.0, 212.0, 225.0, 210.0, 210.0, 200.0, 210.0, 231.0, 231.0, 218.0, 225.0, 321.0, 1018.0, 588.0, 491.0, 456.0, 441.0, 477.0, 427.0, 411.0, 375.0, 377.0, 422.0, 368.0, 359.0, 342.0, 342.0, 400.0, 373.0, 355.0, 358.0, 363.0, 387.0, 357.0, 350.0, 336.0, 328.0, 348.0, 316.0, 301.0, 305.0, 313.0, 599.0, 535.0, 504.0, 498.5, 485.0, 536.0, 505.0, 468.5, 455.0, 470.0, 516.0, 464.0, 452.5, 436.0, 430.0, 519.0, 473.0, 451.0, 433.0, 436.0, 495.0, 456.0, 456.0, 431.0, 437.0, 467.0, 424.0, 400.0, 372.0, 452.0, 1067.0, 804.0, 715.0, 667.5, 632.0, 689.0, 624.0, 575.5, 569.0, 555.0, 605.0, 546.5, 522.0, 495.0, 511.0, 603.5, 532.0, 512.5, 512.0, 491.0, 543.0, 499.0, 472.0, 451.0, 463.0, 500.0, 477.0, 457.0, 435.0, 461.0, 773.0, 705.5, 680.0, 644.0, 639.0, 689.0, 668.0, 620.5, 581.0, 584.0, 667.0, 597.5, 590.5, 568.0, 559.0, 668.0, 605.0, 577.0, 571.0, 566.0, 610.0, 585.5, 575.0, 537.0, 548.0, 586.0, 532.0, 520.0, 491.0, 519.0, 778.0, 703.0, 648.0, 607.0, 586.0, 633.0, 578.0, 552.0, 534.0, 523.0, 610.0, 566.5, 534.0, 525.0, 516.0, 595.0, 552.0, 522.0, 516.5, 518.0, 560.0, 531.0, 513.0, 498.0, 530.0, 578.0, 550.0, 545.0, 602.0, 799.0, 918.0, 644.5, 585.0, 548.0, 525.0, 569.0, 523.0, 496.0, 489.0, 470.0, 526.0, 480.0, 470.0, 455.0, 469.5, 545.0, 466.0, 440.0, 424.0, 440.0, 466.0, 434.0, 415.0, 404.5, 412.0, 449.0, 430.0, 416.0, 408.0, 443.0, 586.0, 495.5, 445.0, 435.0, 434.0, 461.0, 437.0, 416.0, 395.0, 404.0, 437.0, 400.0, 387.0, 381.0, 373.5, 427.0, 404.0, 375.0, 394.0, 380.0, 418.0, 397.0, 386.0, 369.0, 384.5, 411.0, 383.0, 385.0, 420.0, 511.0, 555.0, 415.0, 373.0, 358.0, 359.5, 362.0, 348.5, 339.0, 321.0, 324.5, 348.0, 329.0, 316.0, 315.0, 312.0, 356.0, 321.0, 310.0, 301.0, 310.0, 329.0, 319.0, 305.0, 302.0, 296.0, 315.0, 293.0, 289.0, 289.0, 297.5, 407.0, 342.0, 321.0, 312.0, 304.0, 335.0, 315.0, 302.0, 297.0, 293.5, 308.0, 285.5, 290.0, 283.0, 289.0, 326.0, 300.5, 294.0, 285.0, 281.0, 310.0, 291.0, 289.0, 277.0, 281.0, 306.0, 292.0, 280.5, 279.0, 292.5, 365.0, 316.0, 303.0, 290.0, 287.0, 319.0, 298.0, 287.0, 274.0, 287.0, 303.5, 282.0, 275.0, 271.0, 273.0, 312.0, 289.0, 280.0, 276.0, 274.0, 299.0, 295.0, 281.0, 280.0, 285.0, 306.0, 299.0, 288.0, 295.0, 319.0, 439.0, 379.0, 378.0, 368.0, 353.0, 396.0, 384.0, 363.0, 356.0, 366.0, 406.0, 389.0, 388.5, 378.5, 396.0, 477.0, 460.5, 436.0, 424.0, 443.5, 524.5, 506.0, 503.0, 508.0, 571.5, 687.5, 739.5, 1058.0, 1998.0, 1973.0, 916.5, 459.5, 358.5, 310.0, 274.0, 262.0, 239.0, 225.0, 212.5, 203.0, 214.5, 191.0, 186.0, 176.0, 182.5, 185.0, 170.0, 163.0, 161.0, 162.5, 167.0, 156.0, 156.5, 151.0, 153.0, 157.0, 151.0, 150.0, 140.0, 164.0, 206.0, 164.0, 159.0, 157.5, 156.0, 156.0, 150.0, 148.0, 144.0, 150.5, 161.0, 154.0, 148.0, 152.0, 260.5, 267.0, 168.0, 161.0, 153.0, 150.0, 147.0, 147.0, 148.0, 144.0, 145.0, 148.0, 151.5, 147.0, 145.0, 150.0, 174.0, 142.0, 134.0, 120.0, 113.0, 110.0, 105.0, 101.0, 96.0, 94.0, 98.0, 93.0, 89.0, 86.0, 89.0, 100.0, 121.0, 82.0, 79.0, 78.0, 100.0, 80.0, 74.0, 72.5, 77.0, 91.0, 74.0, 80.0, 86.0, 126.0, 108.0, 63.0, 52.0, 48.0, 46.0, 48.0, 46.0, 44.0, 43.0, 43.0, 45.0, 42.0, 42.0, 42.0, 53.0, 52.0, 38.0, 37.0, 34.0, 33.0, 37.0, 35.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 42.0, 35.0, 34.0, 34.0, 39.0, 75.0, 46.0, 41.0, 39.0, 38.0, 40.0, 36.0, 36.0, 35.0, 38.0, 44.0, 35.0, 35.0, 34.0, 41.0, 63.0, 44.0, 37.0, 33.0, 40.0, 70.0, 37.0, 34.0, 34.0, 41.0, 66.0, 43.0, 40.0, 53.0, 87.0, 43.0, 27.0, 21.0, 22.0, 20.0, 22.0, 19.0, 18.0, 18.0, 19.0, 23.0, 21.0, 20.0, 23.0, 35.0, 23.0, 23.5, 21.0, 23.0, 21.0, 22.0, 20.0, 21.0, 20.0, 20.0, 29.0, 21.0, 20.0, 21.0, 27.0, 69.5, 33.0, 31.5, 30.0, 28.0, 28.0, 25.0, 26.0, 26.0, 28.0, 29.0, 23.0, 22.0, 24.0, 28.0, 23.0, 25.0, 26.0, 25.0, 29.0, 55.0, 27.0, 24.0, 25.0, 29.0, 55.0, 32.0, 27.0, 38.0, 54.0, 77.0, 28.5, 23.0, 19.0, 18.0, 17.0, 15.0, 15.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0, 12.0, 14.0, 13.5, 17.0, 12.0, 11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 12.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 30.0, 18.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 13.0, 12.5, 12.0, 11.0, 11.0, 10.0, 11.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 11.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 12.0, 11.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 13.0]
​
```

which if we plot we can see (qualitatively) a maximal region between roughly 750 and 1100.

[image]

We can see this maximal region more clearly if we smooth the data:

```
pd.Series(data).ewm(span=100).mean().plot()
```

[image]

My question is, what techniques/algorithms can be used to identify the interval say (800, 1200)? I have many such datasets which have different shapes, but all include 1 or 2 maximal "regions".

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I don't have time to do a full answer here, but a mountain climber could help identify peaks and valleys. You could specify it to select the tallest peak and then wait for the graph to dip back down to the level of the valley before it. I have an example of the idea here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66262829/detecting-lines-on-test-cassettes-opencv/66264867#66264867.

Comment: Thanks - will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the mountain climber solution to the problem I mentioned in my comment. I saved the data you posted to a numpy file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/192jp5LvEE0Dc8QVMVmzzuHSehl2_bBLF/view?usp=sharing

Graph after mean filtering and mountain climbing

[image]

Bounds after thresholding based on the value at the start of the rise.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# returns direction of gradient
# 1 if positive, -1 if negative, 0 if flat
def getDirection(one, two):
    dx = two - one;
    if dx == 0:
        return 0;
    if dx > 0:
        return 1;
    return -1;

# detects and returns peaks and valleys
def mountainClimber(vals, minClimb):
    # init trackers
    last_valley = vals[0];
    last_peak = vals[0];
    last_val = vals[0];
    last_dir = getDirection(vals[0], vals[1]);

    # get climbing
    peak_valley = []; # index, height, climb (positive for peaks, negative for valleys)
    for a in range(1, len(vals)):
        # get current direction
        sign = getDirection(last_val, vals[a]);
        last_val = vals[a];

        # if not equal, check gradient
        if sign != 0:
            if sign != last_dir:
                # change in gradient, record peak or valley
                # peak
                if last_dir > 0:
                    last_peak = vals[a];
                    climb = last_peak - last_valley;
                    climb = round(climb, 2);
                    peak_valley.append([a, vals[a], climb]);
                else:
                    # valley
                    last_valley = vals[a];
                    climb = last_valley - last_peak;
                    climb = round(climb, 2);
                    peak_valley.append([a, vals[a], climb]);

                # change direction
                last_dir = sign;

    # filter out very small climbs
    filtered_pv = [];
    for dot in peak_valley:
        if abs(dot[2]) > minClimb:
            filtered_pv.append(dot);
    return filtered_pv;

# run an mean filter over the graph values
def meanFilter(vals, size):
    fil = [];
    filtered_vals = [];
    for val in vals:
        fil.append(val);

        # check if full
        if len(fil) >= size:
            # pop front
            fil = fil[1:];
            filtered_vals.append(sum(fil) / size);
        else:
            # pad to maintain index positions
            filtered_vals.append(0);
    return filtered_vals;

# load from file
data = np.load("data.npy");

# filter and round values
mean_filter_size = 150;
filtered_vals = meanFilter(data, mean_filter_size);

# get peaks and valleys
pv = mountainClimber(filtered_vals, 0);

# filter for the largest climb
biggest_climb = -1;
top_index = None;
for pv_index, feature in enumerate(pv):
    # unpack
    _, _, climb = feature;

    # check climb
    if climb > biggest_climb:
        biggest_climb = climb;
        top_index = pv_index;

# pull out the threshold
start = pv[top_index - 1][0];
threshold = pv[top_index - 1][1];

# look through and find the first spot where the graph drops below threshold
end = None;
for index in range(start + 1, len(data)):
    if data[index] < threshold:
        end = index;
        break;

# draw the bounding lines
markers_x = [start, end];
markers_y = [data[start], data[end]];

# draw plot
x = [a for a in range(len(data))];
fig = plt.figure();
ax = plt.axes();
ax.plot(x, data);
ax.plot(markers_x, markers_y, 'or');
plt.show();
```

Comment: Great solution!